# extension_loaded('curl') fails on google app engine PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl

According to the docs at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#dynamically_loadable_extensions and https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/php_ini#GAE_directives

Adding this to php.ini should load the curl extension:

```
extension = "curl.so"
```

Similarly, adding this too app.yaml should load a curlish extension:

```
google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = "1"
```

However, when trying extension_loaded('curl') via php the results are false. At least in the development server, I have not yet tried in production.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have extension = "curl.so" in php.ini, the extension is loaded automatically. curl & curl_lite can't be both enabled at the same time. You need to pick one or the other.

Comment: tried one or the other, same thing

Comment: Did you change runtime to php55 as suggested by piscator?

Comment: What's your development platform? Have you tried pushing the code to production?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I have been struggling with same problem for a few days

Comment: Are you requesting a URL hosted by Google? Apparently this is not allowed and will cause the request to fail.

Answer (score 3):

Per documents, the

```
google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = "1"
```

should be in the php.ini

Answer (score 1):

I did not yet use this extension in GAE, but did you change runtime: php to runtime: php55 in app.yaml?

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/9PMjrTxVy4w

Answer (score 1):

To use **curl** with google app engine you must create a **php.ini** file in root folder (where is **app.yaml**) with this code:

```
google_app_engine.enable_curl_lite = "1"
```

In the **app.yaml** file add **php55** to **runtime** param:

```
runtime: php55
```

Answer (score 0):

@edmund - I solved this by removing the quote marks. I cannot explain how this makes a difference, but using MacOS and GAE I had to make php.ini include:

```
extension=curl.so
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer is that you may have blacklisted the php.ini file in the app.yaml file :

```
skip_files:
- ^php\.ini$
```